# Using gsub (or similar) to extract from a vector and keep last 4 digits of column names

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to use `gsub` or `substr` or anything similar to keep the column names which consist of `symbols` and a `date`. The `symbols.f` is stored in a vector (which can take on different ticker symbols);

```
symbols.f <- c("NVDA.f", "GOOG.f", "GE.f")
```

I then have the following `colnames()` from the `dput()` below.

```
[1] "GE.f.12.31.2017"  
     [2] "GE.f.12.31.2016"  
     [3] "GE.f.12.31.2015"  
     [4] "GE.f.12.31.2014"  
     [5] "GOOG.f.12.31.2017"
     [6] "GOOG.f.12.31.2016"
     [7] "GOOG.f.12.31.2015"
     [8] "GOOG.f.12.31.2014"
     [9] "NVDA.f.1.28.2018" 
    [10] "NVDA.f.1.29.2017" 
    [11] "NVDA.f.1.31.2016" 
    [12] "NVDA.f.1.25.2015"
```

What I am trying to do is to keep the `ticker` and also keep the `year`or last 4 digits of the column names. So for example for the first two tickers;

```
     [1] "GE2017"  
     [2] "GE2016"  
     [3] "GE2015"  
     [4] "GE2014"  
     [5] "GOOG2017"
     [6] "GOOG2016"
     [7] "GOOG2015"
     [8] "GOOG2014"
```

I am able to extract the last 4 digits or all characters but cannot seem to do it jointly or in one go.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(GE.f.12.31.2017 = c(18211000, NA, 46549000, 21923000, 
5790000, 140110000, 38696000, 53874000, 83968000, 20273000, NA, 
41024000, 6207000, 377945000, 15153000, 134591000, 21400000, 
61893000, 108575000, 82597000, NA, 21122000, NA, 292560000, NA, 
NA, NA, 702000, 125682000, -62127000, NA, 22775000, 64257000, 
-39984000), GE.f.12.31.2016 = c(10525000, NA, 42687000, 22354000, 
2867000, 149029000, 44313000, 50518000, 68070000, 16436000, NA, 
34449000, 1833000, 365183000, 14435000, 136211000, 20772000, 
70364000, 105080000, 83040000, NA, 4688000, NA, 284667000, NA, 
NA, NA, 702000, 139532000, -64412000, NA, 18626000, 75822000, 
-11052000), GE.f.12.31.2015 = c(10372000, NA, 43013000, 22515000, 
5109000, 280896000, 31973000, 54095000, 65526000, 17797000, NA, 
42784000, 3105000, 493071000, 13680000, 197602000, 27453000, 
138270000, 144659000, 79175000, NA, 4836000, NA, 389961000, NA, 
NA, NA, 702000, 140020000, -42454000, NA, 21085000, 98268000, 
14945000), GE.f.12.31.2014 = c(15916000, NA, 23237000, 17639000, 
6566000, 460743000, 35505000, 48070000, 53207000, 13182000, NA, 
44247000, 6183000, 654954000, 12067000, 261424000, 18203000, 
229564000, 186596000, 70801000, NA, 8772000, NA, 518023000, NA, 
NA, NA, 702000, 155333000, -27876000, NA, 14717000, 128159000, 
61770000), GOOG.f.12.31.2017 = c(10715000, 91156000, 18705000, 
749000, 2983000, 124308000, 7813000, 42383000, 16747000, 2692000, 
NA, 3352000, 680000, 197295000, 3137000, 3969000, 10651000, 24183000, 
3943000, 16641000, NA, NA, NA, 44793000, NA, NA, NA, 40247000, 
113247000, -992000, NA, -992000, 152502000, 133063000), GOOG.f.12.31.2016 = c(12918000, 
73415000, 15632000, 268000, 3175000, 105408000, 5878000, 34234000, 
16468000, 3307000, NA, 2202000, 383000, 167497000, 2041000, 3935000, 
5851000, 16756000, 3935000, 7770000, NA, NA, NA, 28461000, NA, 
NA, NA, 36307000, 105131000, -2402000, NA, -2402000, 139036000, 
119261000), GOOG.f.12.31.2015 = c(15409000, 56517000, 13459000, 
491000, 1590000, 90114000, 5183000, 29016000, 15869000, 3847000, 
NA, 3432000, 251000, 147461000, 1931000, 7648000, 4327000, 19310000, 
1995000, 5825000, NA, NA, NA, 27130000, NA, NA, NA, 32982000, 
89223000, -1874000, NA, -1874000, 120331000, 100615000), GOOG.f.12.31.2014 = c(16585000, 
46048000, 9974000, NA, 2637000, 78656000, 3079000, 23883000, 
15599000, 4607000, NA, 3363000, 176000, 129187000, 1715000, 8015000, 
2803000, 16779000, 2992000, 5320000, NA, NA, NA, 25327000, NA, 
NA, NA, 28767000, 75066000, 27000, NA, 27000, 103860000, 83654000
), NVDA.f.1.28.2018 = c(7108000, NA, 1265000, 796000, NA, 9255000, 
NA, 997000, 618000, 52000, NA, 319000, NA, 11241000, 596000, 
2e+06, NA, 1153000, 1985000, 632000, NA, NA, NA, 3770000, NA, 
NA, NA, 7471000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7471000, 6801000), NVDA.f.1.29.2017 = c(1766000, 
5032000, 826000, 794000, NA, 8536000, NA, 521000, 618000, 104000, 
NA, 62000, NA, 9841000, 485000, 2791000, 325000, 1788000, 1985000, 
3e+05, NA, NA, NA, 4079000, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 6108000, -5055000, 
4708000, -16000, 5762000, 5040000), NVDA.f.1.31.2016 = c(596000, 
4441000, 505000, 418000, NA, 6053000, NA, 466000, 618000, 166000, 
NA, 67000, NA, 7370000, 296000, 1434000, 532000, 2351000, 7000, 
533000, NA, NA, NA, 2901000, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 4350000, -4052000, 
4170000, -4000, 4469000, 3685000), NVDA.f.1.25.2015 = c(497000, 
4126000, 474000, 483000, 63000, 5713000, NA, 557000, 618000, 
222000, NA, 91000, NA, 7201000, 293000, 1398000, 471000, 896000, 
1384000, 489000, NA, NA, NA, 2783000, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 3949000, 
-3387000, 3855000, 8000, 4418000, 3578000)), .Names = c("GE.f.12.31.2017", 
"GE.f.12.31.2016", "GE.f.12.31.2015", "GE.f.12.31.2014", "GOOG.f.12.31.2017", 
"GOOG.f.12.31.2016", "GOOG.f.12.31.2015", "GOOG.f.12.31.2014", 
"NVDA.f.1.28.2018", "NVDA.f.1.29.2017", "NVDA.f.1.31.2016", "NVDA.f.1.25.2015"
), row.names = c("Cash And Cash Equivalents", "Short Term Investments", 
"Net Receivables", "Inventory", "Other Current Assets", "Total Current Assets", 
"Long Term Investments", "Property Plant and Equipment", "Goodwill", 
"Intangible Assets", "Accumulated Amortization", "Other Assets", 
"Deferred Long Term Asset Charges", "Total Assets", "Accounts Payable", 
"Short/Current Long Term Debt", "Other Current Liabilities", 
"Total Current Liabilities", "Long Term Debt", "Other Liabilities", 
"Deferred Long Term Liability Charges", "Minority Interest", 
"Negative Goodwill", "Total Liabilities", "Misc. Stocks Options Warrants", 
"Redeemable Preferred Stock", "Preferred Stock", "Common Stock", 
"Retained Earnings", "Treasury Stock", "Capital Surplus", "Other Stockholder Equity", 
"Total Stockholder Equity", "Net Tangible Assets"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this regex work?

```
gsub("\\..*\\.", "", colnames(df))
```

It removes the first and last '.' and everything in between.

```
#[1] "GE2017"   "GE2016"   "GE2015"   "GE2014"   "GOOG2017"
#[6] "GOOG2016" "GOOG2015" "GOOG2014" "NVDA2018" "NVDA2017"
#[11] "NVDA2016" "NVDA2015"

# '\\.' = match a dot, '.' = match anything, '*' = match the previous 0 or more times 
# so \\..*\\. means "anything 0 or more times, preceded by a dot, followed by a dot")  
# the \\ are escapes so the regex can differentiate whether you mean the 
# expression '.' (anything) or '\\.' (actual dot)
```

Comment: Yes thats great, can you quickly talk me through what the function does exactly. You tell it to take all the `.´s  by this section`gsub("\\..*\\."` and then replace it with nothing by this section `"",`. How does the function know to remove all the numbers and the `f``  character? Or have you just told it to keep all characters/numbers outside the `.f.12.31. ?

Comment: @user113156 The pattern starts matching at the first dot on the left.  The `.*` then greedily matches everything up to and including the next dot in the pattern, which also coincides with the last dot.  Then, this is all replaced with empty string (i.e. it is removed).

Comment: @user113156 I added some more explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the answer given by @Ape using `sub` with capture groups:

```
sub("^([^.]+).*?(\\d+)$", "\\1\\2", colnames(df))
```

### Demo